# Javascript div toggle - Fade in not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to have two divs that are able to be toggled with their own respective buttons. They are dramatically different in size so I need the flow of the webpage to change when the div with the most/least content is shown so I can't have them 'position: absolute' on top of each other. One needs to be 'display: none' to take it out of the flow of the webpage, and on the toggle of a button, it should be 'display: block' and the other div should be 'display: none'.

So by doing it this way, the page isn't dramatically longer than it should be and it adjusts to the smaller size of content.

Problem is though, with 'opacity', I cannot get it to fade in. Could anybody help me with this?

```js
//Sections
section1 = document.getElementById("section1");
section2 = document.getElementById("section2");

//Buttons
btn_section1 = document.getElementById("btn_section1");
btn_section2 = document.getElementById("btn_section2");

btn_section2.addEventListener("click", function () {
  section1.classList.remove("active_content");
  section1.style.opacity = "0";
  section1.style.display = "none";

  section2.classList.add("active_content");
});

btn_section1.addEventListener("click", function () {
  section2.classList.remove("active_content");
  section2.style.opacity = "0";
  section2.style.display = "none";
  section1.classList.add("active_content");
});
```

```css
.active_content {
  opacity: 1 !important;
  display: block !important;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out !important;
}

#section1 {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out !important;
}

#section2 {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out !important;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn_section1">Section 1</button>
<button id="btn_section2">Section 2</button>

<div id="section1">
  <h1>Section 1</h1>
</div>

<div id="section2">
  <h1>Section 2</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because of the `display` css property (transition will not work, display is on or of). It may be better to use a few css-classes for fading in/out, something like this snippet (simplified code by using [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation)). For moving elements out of the way (effectively take them out of the page flow) you can use an absolute position with a negative top position.

```js
document.addEventListener("click", evt => {
  const origin = evt.target;
  if (origin.id.startsWith("btn")) {
    document.querySelector(`#${origin.dataset.fadeout}`).classList.remove("fadeIn");
    document.querySelector(`#${origin.dataset.fadein}`).classList.add("fadeIn");
  }
});
```

```css
.fade {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;
  position: absolute;
  /* move out of the way if not used */
  top: -5000px;
}

.fade.fadeIn {
  opacity: 1;
  top: initial;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn_section1" data-fadein="section1" data-fadeout="section2">Section 1</button>
<button id="btn_section2" data-fadein="section2" data-fadeout="section1">Section 2</button>

<div id="section1" class="fade fadeIn">
  <h1>Section 1</h1>
</div>

<div id="section2" class="fade">
  <h1>Section 2</h1>
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
    incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
    exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute 
    irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla 
    pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui 
    officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use setTimeout function with this code.

```
 setTimeout(function() {
     section2.style.display = "none"
 }, 300);

 setTimeout(function() {
     section1.style.display = "none"
 }, 300);
```